# p:commandButton Self-rendering

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to render the same button that execute the ajax call

```
 <p:commandButton id="load"
     actionListener="#{bean.Valid}"
     rendered="#{bean.renderButton}"                 
     value="Load Object"
     ajax="true"
     update="load,group,ip1">
  </p:commandButton>
```

I try to do that via the p:commanButton update and also via RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() in the bean but both of them are not working

```
 RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 requestContext.update("mainForm:load");
```

Any advice what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your button inside something, example :

```
<h:panelGroup id="button-wrapper">
    <p:commandButton id="load"
        actionListener="#{bean.Valid}"
        rendered="#{bean.renderButton}"                 
        value="Load Object"
        ajax="true"
        update="button-wrapper,group,ip1">
     </p:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Ortherwise, your button won't be able to update an element that isn't rendered anymore in the components tree.